# How to filter out unimportant text from html to text conversion?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request, nltk

I am currently scraping couple of websites loading their html contents and striping out all unnecessary parts (tags etc.).
It often appears that I still get a lot of unneeded words which describe the bottom of the page or other subpages of the website.

```
def text_extractor(url):
    try:
        html = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
        for script in soup(["script","style","p"]):
            script.decompose()
        text = soup.get_text()
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
        text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
        text = word_tokenize(text)
        url = str(url).replace('/','').replace('http:','').replace('https:','')
        name = 'textextractor_'+url+'.txt'
        f = open(name,'a')
        f.write(str(text))
        f.close()
        return text
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        pass
```

I am working with this function which makes a good job but most of the generated tokens are irrelevant. Is there a smart way how to just get the text which is relevant for the page and describing for example an event or something similar?

These are examples for unimportant tokens:
 'JournalismBig', 'HollywoodNational', 'SecurityTechVideoSportsThe', 'WiresBreitbart', 'LondonBreitbart', 'JerusalemBreitbart', 'TexasBreitbart', 'CaliforniaPeopleSTORE', 'HomeSubscribe', 'advertisement'

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you give us an example of the "unimportant" text you are talking about?

Comment: Can you gives the url corresponding to the "unimportant tokens" please?